# Equation of motions for simple pendulum in cartesian coordinates instead of generalized coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, coordinate-systems, simulations

I am trying to write the  equation of motions for a simple pendulum but instead of writing them in generalized coordinates ($\theta$), I want to write them in cartesian coordinates (x, y), as I will need them later for further research.

I am writing this matrix in python and it's driving an openGL simulator, this is how I am testing it.

I think my constraint equations are wrong. This is the problem definition I have:

I have a simple pendulum, hinged at (0,0), with an arm of length L with no mass, and on the other end at position (x,y) there is a mass m.
The two forces applied on m are g (pointing downards) (0, -g) and $F_{pend}$ (pointing to 0,0) ($F_{pend}^x, F_{pend}^y$)

The 4 unknowns are $\ddot x, \ddot y, F_{pend}^x, F_{pend}^y$.

Newton's Law gives us the first two equations:

$m \ddot x - F_{\text{pend}}^x = 0$

$m \ddot y - F_{\text{pend}}^y = -mg$

The constraint on the length of the arm gives us the third equation, after taking the second derivative:

$x^2 + y^2 - l^2 = 0$

$2 x \dot x + 2 y \dot y = 0$

$2 \dot x^2 + 2 x \ddot x + 2 \dot y^2 + 2 y \ddot y = 0$

$x \ddot x + y \ddot y = - \dot x^2 - \dot y^2$

At this point I need the 4th equation, which I have no idea what it could be. I currently think is:

$F_{pend} · \langle-y, x\rangle = 0$

$F_{pend}^x (- y) + F_{pend}^y (x) = 0$

This makes the matrix Ax=b for which we can run it to compute x:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
m & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & m & 0 & -1\\
x & y & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -y & x
\end{bmatrix}$

$ x^T = \begin{bmatrix} \ddot x & \ddot y & F_{pend}^x & F_{pend}^y \end{bmatrix}$

$ b^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -mg & - \dot x^2 - \dot y^2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

The way I run the simulator is the following:

Initialize: $(x, y) = (-L, 0)$, $(\dot x, \dot y) = (0, 0)$, $dt = 0.001$

Loop forever:

- Run matrix to compute $(\ddot x, \ddot y)$
- Update position $(x, y) = (x, y) + (\dot x, \dot y) * dt$
- Update velocity $(\dot x, \dot y) = (\dot x, \dot y) + (\ddot x, \ddot y) * dt$

I know this is wrong because when I run this in the simulator I get a very weird motion that looks nothing like a pendulum and the mass drops forever.

Could anyone help me in finding the 4th equation, or even tell me if there are errors in my reasoning?

Comment: You can try a different version of your second equation:$$x=\sqrt(l^2 -y^2)$$, since your current one contains no information about the length $l$ (I am not sure it makes a difference because I was not able to find other solutions to equation 3, but you can try). Moreover, your 4-the equation should contain the velocity and not the positions (I know that the orthogonal vector will be given by that, but it might be easier to debug if you have a problem updating something).What are the initial conditions you used for the pendulum force and did you plot the evolution of the force of the pendulum?

Comment: I don't have initial conditions for the pendulum force as I don't ned to keep track of it. From my understanding after I solve for x the system Ax=b, I can just take care of $\ddot x$ and $\ddot y$.

Comment: And how do you solve Ax=b?

Comment: Ok I think I solved it. There was a mismatch in how openGL was displaying the coordinates of the arm and the mass.

Comment: I solve Ax=b as x=numpy.linalg.solve(A, b)

Comment: Was that the problem?

Comment: *"Could anyone help me in finding the 4th equation, or even tell me if there are errors in my reasoning?"* Please note that "check my work" questions as well as questions asking for a derivation, calculation, proof, etc. are considered off topic here.

Comment: @Jonhy The matrix was correct. $\ddot x$ and $\ddot y$ are independent of $l$. After changing second equation I didn't solve the problem so I checked the code for other possible bugs.

Comment: @BioPhysicist sorry. I guess, since the equations are correct, and I have not found anything similar on the web, this question might become useful for other people. Should I update it?

Comment: @BioPhysicist it seems a very strict interpretation of the _off-topic_ policy is applied here. A lot of questions on this site are of an R&D nature where people are trying to approach a problem from a different perspective, and this is definitely the case here. I am going to vote to re-open this question as I think _it will be useful to others in the future_.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I don't see how a question being useful to others in the future is a sufficient criteria for it to be open. If that was the case then PSE should just become a homework help site, since solutions to homework problems could be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: @BioPhysicist this is not a homework problem IMO. This is not a plug and chug values in an equation type of problem. This is an R&D type of question, where the _op_ wants to tackle a standard problem using a different approach (without generalized coordinates) and the solution is not trivial. I know because I have had the _same exact question_ in my head many years ago before the time of [Physics.SE]. If a user here wants to spend their own time and effort to help another curious person, why should you or the moderators stand in their way. This isn't a question you find in a book or class.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Sorry, I didn't mean to give the impression that I think this is a homework problem. I was just using that as a counterexample of "useful to others = on topic". Additionally, other users wanting to answer the question / having the same question also doesn't determine whether the question is on or off topic.

Comment: @BioPhysicist you are correct that content does not determine if something this off-topic, votes do. And my vote for this one is that it is on-topic **and** useful to others. It has already been useful to me as well as the one answer below. Answering a question requiring a specific numeric answer would be off-topic, but why is a question asking about a method of solving a problem off-topic? 90% of my reputation in this site is answering questions about methods and perspective.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou That's a valid argument. If other users vote to reopen I am fine with that outcome.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to obtain the movement equations in cartesian coordinates a good procedure is to use the lagrarangian formulation. Thus calling $p=(x,y)$ we have

$$
L = \frac 12 m \dot p\cdot\dot p - m g (y-l_0)+\lambda(x^2+y^2-l_0^2)
$$

The movement equations give

$$
\cases{
m\ddot x - 2\lambda x = 0\\
m\ddot y -2\lambda y + m g = 0\\
x^2+y^2-l_0^2=0
}
$$

now deriving the last equation twice regarding $t$  and solving for $\ddot x,\ddot y,\lambda$ we have

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
l_0^2x''(t) & = & x(t) \left(g y(t)-x'(t)^2-y'(t)^2\right) \\
l_0^2y''(t) & = &  y(t) \left(x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2\right) - g x(t)^2\\
2l_0^2\lambda & = &  m \left(g y(t)-x'(t)^2-y'(t)^2\right) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

here $\lambda$ represents the tension on the rope.